# difference between iso-8859 and iso-8859-1,

Tags: iso

is iso-8859 supports for latin character are i need to use iso-8859-1 in java program to read file in chinese character,and what is the difference between this

Answer (score 15):

ISO-8859 is a standard for 8-bit character encodings. 8 bits give you 256 combinations which is OK for most extensions of the Latin alphabet but not for Chinese characters.

ISO-8859-1 is one of the "versions" of ISO-8859 supporting most Western-European languages (French, German, Spanish,...). For Central-European languages (Polish, Czech, Slovak,...) you need ISO-8859-2, etc.

One of the different points between ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-2 is the French letter `è` in ISO-8859-1, which is at the same position as the Czech/Slovak letter `č` in ISO-8859-2. That's why you could not combine these two letters in one text then.

Now with the Unicode it is possible to combine Chinese characters too.

Comment: thanks for u r response so if i need to work with chinese character which iso i need to use

Comment: BTW, an alternative to ISO 8859-1 is ISO 8859-15 which is almost identical to -1 but includes the Euro sign (and a few minor diacritics).

Comment: If you absolutely need an ISO number, then search for ISO 10646.

Comment: @vijay: There is no ISO 8859 codepage for chinese characters, as 8859 can only supply 128 additional characters to the standard ASCII set... but the chinese character set exceeds several thousand "characters". Use a Unicode variant (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32) for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several encodings available for chinese (e.g. simplified and traditional). See 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html for a list.
The most common ones are `GB2312` aka `EUC_CN` for simplified chinese and `Big5` for traditional chinese. I've also seen chinese documents represented in `UTF-8`.