# Encoding with JQuery AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, encoding

I have a html page encoded in:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2">
```

Every content of the page use this charset, and everything looks good. I need to send an Ajax call to PHP server, but when i send a char `á` and send the same value back it shows `ĂĄ` so somehow it changes -i think- to UTF-8... The top of that i need to save this value to an ORACLE DB and in the database it is also saved as an `ĂĄ`...

PHP CODE (ajax.php):

```
<?php 
$p1=$_POST["p1"];
echo "p1:$p1\n";
?>
```

This AJAX setup still not work:

```
 $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'ajax.php',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-2",
    data:{p1:p1,
          p2:p2, 
          }})   
   .always(function() { alert('complete'); });  
}
```

Because as the picture shows (below) the ajax call still sent in UTF-8 character encoding
I appreciate any answer and please do not ask me to change my character encoding to UTF-8, because this is a requirement: (

My other question is why doing nothing this `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-2",`... It is just killing me.

[image]

Comment: why not use utf-8 for all pages?

Comment: Come on:) You kidding me?
From my request: " please do not ask me to change my character encoding to UTF-8"
Short answer: because i am not allowed to change encoding to UTF-8... And this is a big system and every content is written in ISO-8859-2, and of course i can make a script to change html pages content (static texts etc) but it is another story (not allowed)...

Comment: What's with the `<content>` tag do you mean `<meta>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perfect solution would be this:

iconv — `Convert string to requested character encoding`

> string iconv ( string $in_charset , string $out_charset , string $str
>   )
>
> Performs a character set **conversion** on the **string str** from **in_charset**
>   to **out_charset**.

In this particular case:

```
 $encoded_text= iconv("ISO-8859-2", "UTF-8",  $text)
```

I really do not know why but rather of that, the proper format is:

```
 $encoded_text= iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-2",   $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it seems i can use:

utf8_encode() php function: `Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8`

> This function encodes the string data to UTF-8, and returns the
>   encoded version. UTF-8 is a standard mechanism used by Unicode for
>   encoding wide character values into a byte stream. UTF-8 is
>   transparent to plain ASCII characters, is self-synchronized (meaning
>   it is possible for a program to figure out where in the bytestream
>   characters start) and can be used with normal string comparison
>   functions for sorting and such.

The only problem with that: my encoding is ISO-8859-2 and not ISO-8859-1 e.g.

> the French letter è in ISO-8859-1, which is at the same position as
>   the Czech/Slovak letter č in ISO-8859-2

[difference between iso-8859 and iso-8859-1,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711496/difference-between-iso-8859-and-iso-8859-1)
 (given that from another answer)