# Bad character code when parsing xml in exml

Tags: xml, erlang, elixir

I have simple, elixir application:

```
defmodule Interop do
  @moduledoc false
  def main(args) do
        Application.ensure_all_started :inets
        resp = :httpc.request(:get, {'http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/LastA.xml', []}, [], [])
        handle_response(resp)
  end

  defp handle_response({:ok, resp}) do
        {{_, _, _}, _headers, body} = resp
        doc = Exml.parse ~s/#{body}/
  end

  defp handle_response({:error, resp}) do
        IO.puts resp
  end

end
```

When I run it i get

```
** (exit) {:bad_character_code, [60, 116, 97, 98, 101, 108, 97, 95, 107, 117, 114, 115, 111, 119, 32, 116, 121, 112, 61, 34, 65, 34, 32, 117, 105, 100, 61, 34, 49, 54, 97, 49, 56, 54, 34, 62, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 60, 110, 117, 109, 101, 114, 95, ...], :"iso-8859-2"}
    xmerl_ucs.erl:511: :xmerl_ucs.to_unicode/2
    xmerl_scan.erl:709: :xmerl_scan.scan_prolog/4
    xmerl_scan.erl:565: :xmerl_scan.scan_document/2
    xmerl_scan.erl:288: :xmerl_scan.string/2
    lib/exml.ex:11: Exml.parse/2
    (elixir) lib/kernel/cli.ex:76: anonymous fn/3 in Kernel.CLI.exec_fun/2
```

When I download file manually and try to parse it I have the same issue.

My question is, where in my code is mistake? I think, but it only feeling, problem is with `doc = Exml.parse ~s/#{body}/` and encoding of document. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to parse the XML with some other tools, e.g. `xmllint`?

Comment: In Java/JVM langs without any issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `~s/#{body}/` actually changes the encoding of `body` from ISO-8859 to UTF-8 as it treats a list of integers as a list of Unicode codepoints:

```
iex(1)> ~s/#{[241]}/ <> <<0>>
<<195, 177, 0>>
```

while the XML file explicitly says that it's encoded as ISO-8859-2:

```
$ curl -s http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/LastA.xml | head -1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2"?>
```

Your code works if you force the XML parser to use UTF-8 encoding:

```
iex(1)> {:ok, {{_, _, _}, _headers, body}} = :httpc.request(:get, {'http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/LastA.xml', []}, [], [])
{:ok,
 {{'HTTP/1.1', 200, 'OK'},
  [...],
  [60, 63, 120, 109, 108, 32, 118, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 61, 34, 49, 46,
   48, 34, 32, 101, 110, 99, 111, 100, 105, 110, 103, 61, 34, 73, 83, 79, 45,
   56, 56, 53, 57, 45, 50, 34, 63, 62, 13, 10, 60, 116, ...]}}
iex(2)> "#{body}" |> Exml.parse(encoding: :"utf-8")
{:xmlElement, :tabela_kursow, :tabela_kursow, [], {:xmlNamespace, [], []}, [],
 1,
 [{:xmlAttribute, :typ, [], [], [], [tabela_kursow: 1], 1, [], 'A', false},
  {:xmlAttribute, :uid, [], [], [], [tabela_kursow: 1], 2, [], '16a186',
   false}],
 ...}
```

Comment: After reading more about ISO-8859-1 vs ISO-8859-2 I think this might give incorrect values for some characters (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711496/difference-between-iso-8859-and-iso-8859-1). @Koziołek could you check if this gives you incorrect values for any of those characters?

Comment: Looks OK for me. I can ignore issue with values, because I will work only with standard chars.

Answer (score 0):

If you’ll open the downloaded file in the text editor of your chioce, you’ll see it’s in `"ISO-8859-2"` encoding, then it gets converted to `utf-8` by `~s` sigil. The latter conversion assumes that the input is `Latin1` aka `ISO-8859-1`, which is not the case.

`Exml.parse` expects binary input, so there is no way to pass char list received directly to it.

The easiest way to fix the issue would be to use [`codepagex`](https://github.com/tallakt/codepagex):

```
doc = body
      |> :erlang.list_to_binary
      |> Codepagex.to_string!(:iso_8859_2)
      |> Exml.parse(encoding: 'utf-8') # force utf-8
```

When you expect any encoding to be received, the `body` should be parsed for `encoding="ISO-8859-2"` and the value matched is to be used as a parameter in call to `Codepagex.to_string!`:

```
xml = body |> IO.chardata_to_string
[[encoding]] = Regex.scan(~r/(?<=encoding=").*?(?=")/, xml)
doc = xml
      |> Codepagex.from_string!(:iso_8859_1)
      |> Codepagex.to_string!(
           encoding
           |> String.downcase
           |> String.replace("-", "_")
           |> String.to_atom
         )
      |> Exml.parse(encoding: 'utf-8') # force utf-8
```

Comment: I get error like this:
** (Codepagex.Error) Invalid bytes for encoding
    lib/codepagex.ex:497: Codepagex.from_string!/4
    (learn_elixir) lib/interop.ex:15: Interop.handle_response/1